# To know the left position of a array of div in jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have an array of same class div and i want to know the left position of each of the div.so i use the each function. i cant found the exact. it only show the first div left position.

my code is like that..

```
      jQuery.each(jQuery('.selected-item'), function(index, selectpos) {
        selectpos = jQuery('.selected-item').position();
        console.log(index + ':' + selectpos.left);
      });
```

selected-item class is the same class of many divs and i want to know the each div position.

Answer (score 0):

You're not quite getting how to use the `.each()` function. Within the callback for `.each()`, `this` refers to the current DOM element being operated on. (Note that is different to a jQuery object).

So change your code to as follows:

```
  jQuery.each(jQuery('.selected-item'), function(index, selectpos) {
    selectpos = jQuery(this).position();
    console.log(index + ':' + selectpos.left);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're usage of the parameters in the anonymous function of `$.each()` seems a bit odd. See if this helps:

```
  jQuery.each(jQuery('.selected-item'), function(index, element) {
      var selectpos = jQuery(this).position();
      console.log(index + ':' + selectpos.left);
  });
```

You were selecting all of the `.selected-item` elements inside the `each` loop, instead you can refer to the single element that is at the current index of the loop with `this`. Also the anonymous function of `$.each()` is passed two arguments, the `index` of the current item in the loop and the `element` which in this case would be the DOM element in the set of `.selected-item` elements.

You can also do this with a regular `for` loop:

```
  var $selectedItems = $('.selected-item');
  for (var i = 0, len = $selectedItems.length; i < len; i++) {
      var selectpos = $selectedItems[i].position();
      console.log(index + ':' + selectpos.left);
  }
```

The advantage to doing this is that this `for` loop will perform faster. Here is a jsperf to demonstrate the performance difference: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2 (please ignore the edits to the test, someone posted some lewd code)